# Close tags dropping below highlighted line

Tags: html, sublimetext3, emmet

I have minimal experience with HTML script so this may all go horribly wrong here.

Alright so I have a very simple yet very time consuming task of taking complete papers and converting them into HTML script. I'm using Sublime Text 3 with Emmet plugin.

Basically,

```
This is the first header
This is the first paragraph that needs to be tagged

This is the second header
This is the second paragraph that needs to be tagged
```

So super simple I need to put header tags on the headers and paragraph tags on the paragraphs.

What I have been doing is holding Ctrl and manually highlighting the desired text as it is all rather random. Problem is that takes forever to manually highlight the text like that.

I am aware of other ways to highlight such as Ctrl + L for the line. Problem is my close tags end up under the highlighted line.

Example:

```
<h2>This is the first header
</h2><p>This is the first paragraph that needs to be tagged
</p>
```

It's not a big deal but it makes the code harder to go through later and really chaotic.

The same problem persists if I click the corresponding number of the line.

Seeing as I have hundreds of pages to enter and even more headers, paragraphs, and pictures to properly tag; I'm looking for a solution to the tag dropping below the line or a faster method to entering text.

So, is there a fast method for entering text from a word document to Sublime text and quickly get the corresponding tags? e.g. `<h2>,<h3>,<p>,<ul>,<li>` and so on.

Any help will save my sanity, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, it automatically selects the entire line, and moves the cursor down to the first position on the following line. There are two ways around this. The first is to place the cursor in the first position on the line you want to select, then just hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> and the line will be selected, with the cursor now sitting in the last position on that same line. Alternatively, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow) to move the cursor from the first position on the next line to the last position on the selected line. Either way, you can now hit the key combo in Emmet for inserting a tag pair, and you're all set.